# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to print out a dictionary in the following format. I want to do this because I need to graph some trends in D3 using the JSON format. For this trend, I am counting the number of murders in each state within each decade (1980s to 2010s).

I am able to output the file and everything but since I am trying to create a graph, the format of the data in the JSON file needs to be very specific in terms of labeling each key, value pair in the dictionary in the output.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Wyoming.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
year = df['Year']
state = df['State']
freq = dict()

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    currYear = year.iloc[i]
    if(currYear >= 1980 and currYear < 1989):
        currDecade = 1980
    elif(currYear >= 1990 and currYear < 2000):
        currDecade = 1990
    elif(currYear >= 2000 and currYear < 2010):
        currDecade = 2000
    elif(currYear >= 2010):
        currDecade = 2010
    currState = state.iloc[i]
    if currDecade in freq:
        if currState in freq[currDecade]:
            freq[currDecade][currState] += 1
        else:
            key = {currState: 1}
            freq[currDecade].update(key)
    else:
        key = {currDecade:{currState: 1}}
        freq.update(key)

#print(freq)
freq1 = [{'Decade': d, 'State': [{'State': s, 'Freq': f}]} for d, s, f in freq.items()]
print(freq1)
```

I am getting the error **"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)"**

I expect the output to be as given below.

```
[{"Decade": "1980", "State": [{"State": "California", "Freq": 29591}, {"State": "Massachusetts", "Freq": 1742}, ...}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dict.items()` only iterates tuples with two elements: the key and value.

```python
freq1 = []
for decade, states in freq.items():
    freq1.append({
        'Decade': decade,
        'State': []
    })
    for state, freq in states.items():
        freq1['State'].append([{'State': state, 'Freq': freq}])
print(freq1)
```

I think the code is more readable this way. However if you still prefer the one-line list comprehension solution, here it is:

```python
freq1 = [{'Decade': d, 'State': [{'State': s, 'Freq': f} for s, f in ss.items()]} for d, ss in freq.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is `for d, s, f in freq.items()`, since `freq.items()` returns an iterable over `(key, value)` pairs in freq. Since you have nested dicts, try this:

```
freq1 = [{'Decade': d, 'State': [{'State': s, 'Freq': f} for s, f in sdict.items()]}
  for d, sdict in freq.items()
]
```

Comment: I think you also need to aggregate the states by decade.

Comment: The output that I am getting from this is not the same as my expected output. I want the states to be in the decade group instead of the decade repeating for each state.